# What is the rationale behind the typeid operator ignoring cv-qualifiers

Tags: c++, typeid, typeinfo

From the C++ language standard, §5.2.8 from ISO/IEC 14882:2003, quote,

> The top-level cv-qualifiers of the lvalue expression or the type-id that is the operand of typeid are always ignored.

What is the rationale for this decision. It punched a hole in the type system and is counter-intuitive. The const information (or the volatile part) is known at compile time, so there would be no overhead if typeid just took account of cv-qualifiers.

Comment: So your response to people complaining about RTTI bloat is to generate four times as much?

Comment: You can use `decltype` for compile-time analysis; the point of RTTI is for runtime analysis that cannot be determined at compile-time

Comment: @M.M Quote, "Note, that this is a change from the rules proposed in N1607, where the cv-qualifiers, or l- or rvalueness did
not contribute to the result of decltype." (from N1705). It is not easy to make cv-qualifiers to play well with other parts of C++.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the ability to overload nonstatic member functions with `const`, `volatile`, and `const volatile` variants (see [class.mfct.nonstatic]), types `D`, `const D`, `volatile D`, and `const volatile D` (for some non-cv-qualified type `D`) are not unrelated; the standard specifies in [basic.type.qualifier] that for each *cv-unqualified type*, there is a distinct `const`-qualified, `volatile`-qualified, and `const volatile`-qualified "version" of the type having the same representation and alignment requirements. If it were possible for `D` and `const D` to be unrelated to one another (e.g. by having different representations, storage requirements, or in the case of classes, different members), then a lot of the language would break down.

For example, an object of type `D&` is implicitly convertible to `const D&`, `volatile D&`, and `const volatile D&` (see [conv.qual]). However, if `D` was allowed to be unrelated to `const D`, then this conversion would not make sense.

Consider also that a number of places in the standard specify that top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored:

- [over.load] specifies:

  > Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of `const` and/or `volatile` are equivalent. That is, the `const` and `volatile` type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.
- [temp.param] specifies:

  > The top-level *cv-qualifiers* on the *template-parameter* are ignored when determining its type.
- [basic.life], when specifying how storage of an object whose lifetime ended can be reused, mentions:

  > the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers)
- [over.best.ics] specifies:

  > Any difference in top-level cv-qualification is subsumed by the initialization itself and does not constitute a conversion. [*Example:* a parameter of type `A` can be initialized from an argument of type `const A`. The implicit conversion sequence for that case is the identity sequence; it contains no “conversion” from `const A` to `A`. ]
- [temp.deduct.call] specifies:

  > If `A` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `A`’s type are ignored for type deduction.

  and:

  > If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `P`’s type are ignored for type deduction.

  ([temp.deduct.conv] has similar language.)
- [except.throw] specifies:

  > A *throw-expression* initializes a temporary object, the type of which is determined by removing any top-level *cv-qualifiers* from the static type of the operand of `throw` and adjusting the type from “array of `T`” or “function returning `T`” to “pointer to `T`” or “pointer to function returning `T`”, respectively.
- [except.handle] specifies:

  > A *handler* is a match for a *throw-expression* with an object of type `E` if
  >
  > — The handler is of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&` and `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), or …

All of these would have to be changed if `D`, `const D`, `volatile D`, and `const volatile D` were allowed to be unrelated types.

Comment: However, f(T&) and f(const T&) are different functions. To be consistent, these two should be deemed the same. Then we can consistently say that cv-qualifiers don't introduce sub-types, and they only and attributes to specific objects of that type.

Comment: They certainly are different types. The logic in your 2nd paragraph is no good either; `Derived&` can be implicitly converted to `Base&` but I doubt anyone would argue that this doesn't make sense, or that they are the same type.

Comment: Derived denotes a sub-type of Base, that makes Derived& being implicitly converted to Base& as expected. Considering functions f(int), f(const int), f(int&) and f(const int&), the first two have the same signature, but the  latter pair are overloaded functions. IMHO, this is a flaw of language design. It would be better that const and volatile be made into mandatory compiler intrinsics,  not an hard-wired in the type system of the language.

Comment: @M.M By "not make sense", I am referring to the hypothetical scenario where `D` and `const D` are allowed to be different types. This would mean that you would be able to define a `class D` and a `class const D` which could have completely different members and functionality. It wouldn't be possible to implicitly convert a reference-to `D` to a reference-to `const D` because the two types would have no relation to one another. Converting a `Derived&` to a `Base&` makes sense because a `Derived` is-a `Base`.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien `D` and `const D` are different types; this is not hypothetical. It says in the standard dozens of times that they are different types. `class const D` is a syntax error . Your comment makes no sense, it seems like you believe that something cannot be a type unless it was defined by `class X`

Comment: @M.M I am well aware that `class const D` is not allowed. I was simply trying to illustrate my point of what being able to define unrelated types `D` and `const D` might look like in hypothetical syntax; I wasn't writing literally. Also, of course I do not believe that `class X` is the only way to define a type. There are, after all, fundamental types. Maybe I would be more clear in my answer by using the word "unrelated" instead of "distinct".

Answer (score 1):

Because `typeid` returns dynamic type if the operand is a [polymorphic object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects). Cv-qualifiers are designed to be compile-time limits, and additional information has to be recorded at runtime to retrieve cv-qualifiers of dynamic type, so it is rational to ignore top-level cv-qualifiers.

For operand of type or non-polymorphic object, `typeid` ignores top-level cv-qualifiers for consistency. Otherwise, for example, the following `assert` will fire unexpectedly:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base {};

const Derived *d = new Derived;
const Base *b = d;

assert(typeid(*b) == typeid(decltype(*d))); // should not fire
```